# Issue with HSTS which is don't on the server

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2

We have a servers on Amazon ec2 for developer needs, and we have a web-site which is running under the docker container.for testing new features on site
All works perfectly, but yesterday about 70% of my colleagues has a trouble to access to this dev site. The SSL errors and No response from the server errors is occurs. And 30% of team (me included) has absolutely no problems to access the website ( all pc's) on the same subnet.
We use Nginx and in the config file has no strict access mode, the server listen on port 80 and no redirect options. No security certificates too btw
And a bit about browsers ( almost all Google chrome users has a error because of redirecting to https, Safari too btw) (but in case of Mozila users they almost don't have error and site opens under http protocol) 
I'm tried to clear the HSTS cache in chrome, try to reinstall the browser, and I don't have a clue what's going wrong.

Comment: Try hitting the url with `curl -v <url>` and see if it works. And check the the chrome network tools logs and see what happens?

Comment: If your production system at `example.com` sets `Strict-Transport-Security: ... includeSubDomains` then `qa.example.com` should be affected... by design.  Not enough info here to know whether that is relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your domain is not in chromium list (https://www.chromium.org/hsts), here is the link for the source of the full [list](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json).

You could remove your domain by using this form: https://hstspreload.org/removal/

The fastest workaround to this is to terminate all your HTTPS traffic by using a load balancer (ELB) HAproxy, or either Nginx.